# populate a textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I am using the SCEditor and want a button on forum posts or articles comments called "Quote" where it grabs the text from the message and pastes it into the textarea, i have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict(); //disable global $ for jQuery
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(function(){
    $('#quote').click(function() {
        $('textarea').sceditor('instance').insert("[quote=admin]Some text[/quote]");
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

Now that works, it will put "[quote=admin]Some text[/quote]" into the textarea. Problem is I need that to be dynamic somehow so i don't have to copy that code above every comment if that makes sense? So instead of this:

```
insert("[quote=admin]Some text[/quote]");
```

That section would grab all the text from the box below it? Rather than me manually replacing the quoted bit with the text in the post.

So basically replace the quoted bit above with the contents from different divs based on clicking a Quote link?

Comment: It sounds like you are making progress towards a solution. What is the question? I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Also can you post the html code or the script used to generate it?

Comment: My question is how do i replace "[quote=admin]Some text[/quote]" with an elements contents? Like a div for example?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression like in this simple example

```
<textarea id="ta" rows="5" cols="20">
  [quote=admin]Some text[/quote]
</textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="rep()" />
<br />
<div id="dv" style="width:100px; height:100px; border:black 1px solid;">
  Some div content
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function rep() {
    var tatxt = $("#ta").val();
    var dvtxt = $("#dv").html();
    var newtxt = tatxt.replace(/\[quote\=admin\].*?\[\/quote\]/ig, dvtxt);
    $("#ta").val( newtxt );
  }
</script>
```

[You can see it work here](http://jsfiddle.net/h9rgf/).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the structure of your entries. Let's assume the "quote" button and the div id="entry"  are on the same level nested inside a parent  or another container.

```
<div id="wholeThing">
    <div id="entry"> ....... </div>
    <!-- other stuff goes here -->
    <input type="button" name="quote" ......>
</div>
```

Then you can go with this:

```
$(this).parent().find("#entry").text();
```

If you exactly know where the content resides, you can iterate over previous elements in the hierarchy.

```
$(this).prev().prev().text(); // if content container is 2 elements in front
```

For the buttons click handler you can set a class or use its name attribute:

```
$('div input[name="quote"]').click(function() {  // for name attribute
    $('textarea').sceditor('instance').insert("[quote=admin]Some text[/quote]");
});
```

With a class equal to all "quote" buttons:

```
$('.className').click(function(){ ...
```

If it is the only input element in every entry:

```
$('div input').click(function() { ...
```